# Unix - Sorting based on field position

Tags: shell, sorting, unix

I am trying to sort a file based on field position using the following command:

```
sort  -d -k 2.42,44 -k 4.65,74
```

But when I check my output file whether it got sorted (sort -c) one of the lines is always out of order. The file to be sorted is given below:

```
000835NMSEFT 20140626095038403536                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
010835           577300053D0000000031860CZZBCCP01122000496   DA 2270000323                         133052649999999999901121000358   DA 1235565067                         201406301EG11388791                    1953760980999999999                                                                                       TN HCCLAIMPMT                    40520140625PRREEP                                                                              21555 OXNARD STREET                                    WOODLAND HILLS                CA91367    BLEDI SOLUTIONS                           TE8002273983                                                                                                                                                                              IC                                        URwww.anthem.com/provider/router                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              PETWIN CITIES COMMUNITY HOS                                   XX1396778197          FILE 57446                                             LOS ANGELES                   CA90074    TJ 752918765-0506330000-000      PN 050633-003                                                                                  EY           DCCP13305264991953760980                                 050633-003NMSINS          201406255004000270000323 0003230001                 2014I 050633-003   00004                                                           01505000323050633-003   00004
000835NMSEFT 20140626095038403536                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
010835           577300054D0000000002162CZZHCCP01122000496   DA 2270000323                         133052649999999999901122000030   DA 1452500273                         201406301EG11388792                    1953760980999999999                                                                                       TN HCCLAIMPMT                    40520140625PRREEP                                                                              21555 OXNARD STREET                                    WOODLAND HILLS                CA91367    BLEDI SOLUTIONS                           TE8002273983                                                                                                                                                                              IC                                        URwww.anthem.com/provider/router                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              PESCRIPPS CLINIC                                              XX1538297726          10666 N TORREY PINES RD S                              LA JOLLA                      CA92037    TJ 870737749-0000000000-000                                                                                                     BY           DCCP13305264991953760980                                 870737749 NMSPRF          201406254004000270000323 0003230001                 2014P 870737749-00300010                                                           01405000323870737749-00300010
000835NMSEFT 20140626095038403536                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
010835           577300074D0000000002000CACHCCP01191179439   DA 3350209432                         191179439099999999901121000358   DA 1459336554                         201406301EG11388801                    1953760980999999999                                                                                       TN HCCLAIMPMT                    40520140625PRALVORD UNIFIED SCHOOL DISTRICT                                                    21555 OXNARD STREET                                    WOODLAND HILLS                CA91367    BLEDI SOLUTIONS                           TE8002273983                                                                                                                                                                              IC                                        URwww.anthem.com/provider/router                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              PEUSC CARE MEDICAL GROUP IN                                   XX1902846306          50938 FILE                                             LOS ANGELES                   CA90074    TJ 954540991-0000000000-000                                                                                                     EY           DCCP19117943901953760980                                 954540991 NMSPRF          201406254022603350209432 2094320001                 2014P 954540991    00045                                                           01403209432954540991    00045
000835NMSEFT 20140626095038403536                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
010835           577300075D0000000021553CABHCCP01122000496   DA 2640001855                         194147704099999999901121141819   DA 0009605886                         201406301EG11388802                    1953760980999999999                                                                                       TN HCCLAIMPMT                    40520140625PRHOOPA VALLEY TRIBAL COUNCIL                                                       21555 OXNARD STREET                                    WOODLAND HILLS                CA91367    BLEDI SOLUTIONS                           TE8002273983                                                                                                                                                                              IC                                        URwww.anthem.com/provider/router                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              PEEUREKA FAMILY PRACTICE IN                                   XX1114965761          2675 HARRIS ST                                         EUREKA                        CA95503    TJ 941724607-0000000000-000      PN 941724                                                                                      BY           DCCP19414770401953760980                                 941724607 NMSPRF          201406254023202640001855 0018550001                 2014P 941724607    00013                                                           01405001855941724607    00013
000835NMSEFT 20140626095038403536                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
010835           577300076D0000000004819CABBCCP01122000496   DA 2640001855                         194147704099999999901121141819   DA 990487159                          201406301EG11388803                    1953760980999999999                                                                                       TN HCCLAIMPMT                    40520140625PRHOOPA VALLEY TRIBAL COUNCIL                                                       21555 OXNARD STREET                                    WOODLAND HILLS                CA91367    BLEDI SOLUTIONS                           TE8002273983                                                                                                                                                                              IC                                        URwww.anthem.com/provider/router                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              PEHUMBOLDT RADIOLOGY MED GR                                   XX1326154196          PO BOX 6428                                            EUREKA                        CA95502    TJ 942188987-0000000000-000                                                                                                     EY           DCCP19414770401953760980                                 942188987 NMSPRF          201406254023202640001855 0018550001                 2014P 942188987    00004                                                           01405001855942188987    00004
000835NMSEFT 20140626095038403536                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
010835           577300079D0000000010320CDAHCCP01122000496   DA 4000155328                         133017499699999999901323070380   DA 485008267910                       201406301EG11388804                    1953760980999999999                                                                                       TN HCCLAIMPMT                    40520140625PRVIASAT, INC                                                                       21555 OXNARD STREET                                    WOODLAND HILLS                CA91367    BLEDI SOLUTIONS                           TE8002273983                                                                                                                                                                              IC                                        URwww.anthem.com/provider/router                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              PEWEST PACIFIC MEDICAL LABO                                   XX1124050380          PO BOX 2339                                            SANTA FE SPGS                 CA90670    TJ 954391299-0000000000-000                                                                                                     BY           DCCP13301749961953760980                                 954391299 NMSPRF          201406254025104000155328 1553280001                 2014P 954391299    00025                                                           01405155328954391299    00025
```

Comment: Try to give some minimal example together with what you get and what you _want_ to get. Also, use the top bar to change the format of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. The number after the decimal is a character position *within the field* (not from the beginning of the line). And you need to repeat the field number after the commas. So:

```
sort  -k 2.25,2.27 -k 4,4
```